# UILabel decrease height, auto layout weird animation

Tags: ios, animation, autolayout, uilabel

I have expandable UILabel:

```
func expandDescriptionLabel() {
    let calculatedHeightDescriptionLabel = lblDescription.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(lblDescription.frame.width, CGFloat.max)).height
    expanded = true
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
        self.cnsDescriptionHeight.constant = calculatedHeightDescriptionLabel
        self.hideMoreButton()// this line means nothing, results are the same with this line commented out
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })

}

func reduceDescriptionLabel() {
    expanded = false
    self.cnsDescriptionHeight.constant = 60
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
        self.showMoreButton() // this line means nothing, results are the same with this line commented out
        self.lblDescription.setNeedsLayout();
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

When expanding animation looks just fine, but when height is decreasing strange things happen. Look at GIF below. I tried already `CGAffineTransformScale` and putting UILabel in UIView and then animating a UIView.

Question is how to make the last part of animation more smooth.
As you can see when Labels height is decreasing, text is moving up and then  suddenly appear in correct place(without animation).

[image]

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Sorry, edited already.

Comment: Well, I suppose it all depends on what `showMoreButton()` does. But you have elected not to reveal that, so who knows what's going on here?

Comment: It just shows Read More button. Executing code with commented out `showMoreButton()` gives the same result. I think the problem is with UILabel, but I did not find any posts about this issue.

Comment: try to call         self.showMoreButton()
in animation completion block

Comment: Thanks for help @Kavya, but as you can see in edited post, calling `self.showMoreButton` is not the point. The issue is connected with UILabel itself.